# Protractor - how to handle pop-up from Chrome

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using Protractor and I'm wondering how to handle this pop-up from Chrome.
I want to click the button "Open magnet URI".
Check out the picture to see what I mean.

[picture of pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DXCw.jpg)

When the button is being clicked an external program will start.

I have tried with browser.switchTo().alert().accept();

But I always get "no such alert".

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below `chrome option` in your `config`

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        // disable "chrome pop-up"
        'args': ['disable-infobars=true','--disable-popup-blocking'], 

        // disable Password manager popup
        'prefs': {
            'credentials_enable_service': false
        }
    }
},
```

Hope it hleps you

Comment: @niclas Do mark the answer as correct if it really resolved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for an answer

I just found a solution for my problem

Added this to my config

```
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--window-size=375,667',         //'--headless', '--disable-gpu',
        'disable-infobars',
      ],
      'prefs': {
        protocol_handler: {
          excluded_schemes: {
            'bankid': false
          }
        }
        }
    }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

As per new chrome drivers disable-infobars is not working. Add following to make it work in your chrome options:

```
'excludeSwitches': ['enable-automation'],
'useAutomationExtension': false
```